# If Statement in SQL Server (case when?)

Tags: sql-server

I have two fields in SQL:

```
Improvement Type
25  Daily
25  Weekly
25  Monthly
```

I want to write  an if statement in SQL Server saying”

```
If type = daily than Improvement/365
If type =  weekly than improvement/52
If type = monthly than  improvement/12
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Case type when 'Daily' then Improvement/365 when 'Weekly' then... end?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE [Type] 
   WHEN 'Daily' THEN [Improvement] / 365
   WHEN 'Weekly' THEN [Improvement] / 52
   WHEN 'Monthly' THEN [Improvement] / 12
 END AS CalculatedField
FROM [MyTableNameHere]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @TimLentine is correct, obvious, appropriate and should be used. Here's an approach that does not use `CASE`, is unmaintainable, unreliable, likely performs worse, and in short, should probably never appear in production code for any reason, unless you want to antagonize your coworkers.

```
SELECT 
    [Improvement] / SUBSTRING(0xc2a016d34, LEN([Type]) * 2 % 7, 2)
FROM [MyTableNameHere]
```

If you understand why this works, you also understand why it should not be used. I supply it for entertainment purposes only.